# Effective way to wait until file upload has finished (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently developing an application with React and Mongoose (MongoDB) where I upload a text file, that contains roughly around 9000+ lines, containing JSON. Each line is important and I need to be able to store it in the database to be accessible later.

I have set up two functions, one that reads the file and one that creates a model for each request and saves it to MongoDB.

**Function to read each line**

```
const createAndReadFile = async (filePath) => {
    //create a read stream of the File
    let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, 'utf8');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {
        let parsedJSONLine = JSON.parse(line);
            createAndAddToDB(parsedJSONLine);
    }
};
```

**Function to add to the database each line**

```
const createAndAddToDB = async (jsonRequest) => {
    try {
        let request = new Request(jsonRequest);

        await request.save();
    } catch (error) {}
};
```

**My question is, what's the most effective way to wait until all the lines have been converted to a model and saved in the database ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` to await the resolution of all promises that are created in the for-await loop:

```js
var promises = [];
for await (const line of rl) {
  let parsedJSONLine = JSON.parse(line);
  promises.push(createAndAddToDB(parsedJSONLine));
}
return Promise.all(promises);
```

Alternatively, you can perform the conversion in the for-await loop and write to the database in a batch:

```js
var promises = [];
for await (const line of rl) {
  let parsedJSONLine = JSON.parse(line);
  promises.push(convertToDBFormat(parsedJSONLine));
}
return Promise.all(promises).then(function(converted) {
  return addToDBBatch(converted);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const createAndReadFile = async (filePath) => {
    //create a read stream of the File
    let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, 'utf8');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for (const line of rl) {
        let parsedJSONLine = JSON.parse(line);
            await createAndAddToDB(parsedJSONLine);
    }
    
    return 'file is processed';
};
```

You have written it correctly, I guess. When the loop is over, it will be the last line of the file.

Now, if there are any lines that are not saved you can push them over to the failed array maybe and save them in the batches.

Suggestion: **also, instead of saving every line to DB every time that's a lot of requests 9000+ (lines), you should use batch insert.
When you are out of the loop, you can again check if there are lines that were not saved. Re-run the batch save function and you are good to go.**

Comment: No, the `file is processed` line is reached when the 9000+ insertion statements have been _sent_ to the database. It does not wait until the database reports back whether they have been successfully inserted. In other words: `createAndAddToDB` returns a promise, but for-await does not wait for its resolution. And if you prefix `createAndAddToDB` with `await`, the second line will be sent to the DB only after the first has been succesfully written, which slows things down.

Comment: First of all, when you save data to the DB, it returns whether the data is not saved or not. It is a promise we can check the response. Also, it is not an efficient practice to have 9000+ promises and wait for their resolution. The reason I suggested batch processing is to make sure the data is saved in batches and see how DB responds back. If you have left over save them again, only when order doesn't matter.

Comment: `createAndAddToDB ` is an async function and it will return only when `save` is successful or failed. That's why `for of await` will help to keep the code waiting for the current execution.

Comment: DB batch operations are a good idea, I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @HeikoTheißen and Apoorva Chikara for the suggestions. Converting to the appropriate format and saving the lines with batches was the optimal solution! Appreciate the help!